# Create Linear Regression Plot from .csv from R GUI

Tags: r, gwidgets

I am a beginner in R programming.  I have coded a basic R script that allows the user to choose a .csv file with 2 columns (X and Y), plot these on a graph to show linear regression and print the related rsquared value of the XY relationship.

Can someone explain the basics of adding this code to gWidgets so I can have a GUI with two buttons? - button1 will be a file.choose() to select the .csv file (i've seen this code elsewhere), button2 will run linear regression and output the plot to a display window.

I've been through all the gWidgets tutorials and code snippets but it is still not clear to me how to carry out a simple function as I have described above.  I think I thought it would be possible to just cut and paste my existing R code into a gWidgets button, but I now see this is not the case.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Kind Regards

```
#CALCULATES LINEAR REGRESSION SCATTER PLOT FOR TWO COLUMNS - X and Y
# ALSO PRINTS r2 VALUE ON PLOT

#READ IN THE .CSV FILE - FILE SHOULD CONTAIN TWO COLUMNS WITH NO HEADER - X and Y
#CREATE DATAFRAME
test1 <- read.csv("C:/Data/test.csv", header=FALSE)

#ASSIGN THE DATA IN EACH COLUMN TO A VARIABLE NAME
X1 <- test1$V1
Y1 <- test1$V2

#PLOT DATA WITH APPROPRIATE LABELS
plot(X1, Y1, xlab="X", ylab="Y")

#CALCULATE THE BEST FIT LINE AND PRINT R2 VALUE ON PLOT
abline(fit <- lm(X1 ~ Y1, data=test1), col='red')
legend("topright", bty="n", legend=paste("r2 is", format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, digits=4)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something simple like:

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="tcltk") ## or RGtk2 ...

w <- gwindow("Your GUI", visible=FALSE)
g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)

upload <- gfilebrowse("Select a csv file", cont=g)
btn <- gbutton("Do it", cont=g)
enabled(btn) <- FALSE

filename <- NULL
do_it <- function(...) {
  message("Read csv file in filename")
  message("make graphic")
  message("make summary")
}

addHandlerChanged(upload, handler=function(h, ...) {
  val <- svalue(upload)
  if(!is.na(val)) {
    filename <<- val
    enabled(btn) <- TRUE
  }
})
addHandlerChanged(btn, handler=do_it)

visible(w) <- TRUE
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for this, it's a very useful structure for someone who is starting out. What I still don't understand is how I can replace the message you've written in the function with the request to plot the XY data. Cheers